# Array slicing in FORTRAN 77

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, fortran77

According to my search, array slicing feature was added first in Fortran 90. I need something similar to this feature in FORTRAN 77. I have a matrix and I just want to pass one row of it to subroutine. Actually I can assign the values at that row to another array but I want something practical and fast. Is there any trick for that?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @casey Intel Fortran Compiler 12.0

Comment: Did you notice which century we now have in your calendar? Fortran 90 is already older then many people here. FORTRAN 77 has right to be left to rest in peace.

Comment: You can of course "slice" *columns* in f77, and the usual approach to this issue was/is to arrange your arrays so the data you routinely need to "slice" is in columns.

Answer (score 3):

You note in the comments that you are using Intel Fortran 12.0.  This compiler is a modern Fortran compiler with partial Fortran 2003 and limited Fortran 2008 support.  As such, this compiler supports array slicing, so you shouldn't have any problems using that syntax in your code.

If you concern is maintaining pure FORTRAN 77 code, I personally wouldn't worry about that unless you were limited to using ancient compilers.  All of the major vendors distribute modern Fortran compilers and a standard FORTRAN 77 program is also a valid Fortran 90 program.  Unless you are forcing the compiler to use strict FORTRAN 77 compliance (and as so much old FORTRAN code uses non standard extensions, I find this unlikely; nor do I see a way in intel fortran to do this) there should be no issues introducing Fortran 90 syntax into your program.